# Change the Java tea icon from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, syntax, icons, jframe

I create a JFrame but it displays a custom Java icon on the header-upper corner. I want to change the icon to my own icon.Is it possible to do? How can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to change the icon.
Try this:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("path of your image");
frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
frame.setVisible(true);
```

**OR**

```
BufferedImage  image = ImageIO.read(frame.getClass().getResource("path of your image"));
frame.setIconImage(image);
frame.setVisible(true);
```